# How to filter a set of SKUs with each having different quantity required from a large dataset without doing it mannually

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have list of 300 SKUs and each having different requested qty, I have to filter it from a large inventory data sets to find out the bin no's to pick. Right now am doing it manually. Lookup and filter functions in Excel and google sheets are not helpful. Kindly suggest.

If i applying a formula,It should return only the specific nos of counts which i required from large data sets.

Comment: please share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) with example of your data and desired result.